# What is the effects for this empty select-case-default code block？

Tags: go, select, case, channel

I'm trying to understand a pool library codes, and when instancing a pool struct, call a function named `startCleanerLocked(t Duration)`, in this function, there's one empty `select...case...default...` code block, I cann't understand what is the effect for this code block.

`Pool Interface` is:

```
// Pool interface.
type Pool interface {
    Get(ctx context.Context) (io.Closer, error)
    Put(ctx context.Context, c io.Closer, forceClose bool) error
    Close() error
}
```

`List Struct` implement `Pool Interface`,

```
type List struct {
    // New is an application supplied function for creating and configuring a
    // item.
    //
    // The item returned from new must not be in a special state
    // (subscribed to pubsub channel, transaction started, ...).
    New func(ctx context.Context) (io.Closer, error)

    // mu protects fields defined below.
    mu     sync.Mutex
    cond   chan struct{}
    closed bool
    active int
    // clean stale items
    cleanerCh chan struct{}

    // Stack of item with most recently used at the front.
    idles list.List

    // Config pool configuration
    conf *Config
}
```

when Create a new pool, `startCleanerLocked(t Duration)` function be called:

```
// NewList creates a new pool.
func NewList(c *Config) *List {
    // check Config
    if c == nil || c.Active < c.Idle {
        panic("config nil or Idle Must <= Active")
    }
    // new pool
    p := &List{conf: c}
    p.cond = make(chan struct{})
    p.startCleanerLocked(time.Duration(c.IdleTimeout))
    return p
}
```

and in `startCleanerLocked(t Duration)`, there is a `select...case...default`:

```
// startCleanerLocked
func (p *List) startCleanerLocked(d time.Duration) {
    if d <= 0 {
        // if set 0, staleCleaner() will return directly
        return
    }
    if d < time.Duration(p.conf.IdleTimeout) && p.cleanerCh != nil {
        select {
        case p.cleanerCh <- struct{}{}:
        default:
        }
    }
    // run only one, clean stale items.
    if p.cleanerCh == nil {
        p.cleanerCh = make(chan struct{}, 1)
        go p.staleCleaner()
    }
}
```

what's the effect for this code block:

```
select {
    case p.cleanerCh <- struct{}{}:
    default:
}
```

Seems it's nothing to do...

and in `staleCleaner()`, there is a same empty `select..case...case`, also cannot undestand its effect:

```
// staleCleaner clean stale items proc.
func (p *List) staleCleaner() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
        case <-p.cleanerCh: // maxLifetime was changed or db was closed.
        }
        p.mu.Lock()
        if p.closed || p.conf.IdleTimeout <= 0 {
            p.mu.Unlock()
            return
        }
        for i, n := 0, p.idles.Len(); i < n; i++ {
            e := p.idles.Back()
            if e == nil {
                // no possible
                break
            }
            ic := e.Value.(item)
            if !ic.expired(time.Duration(p.conf.IdleTimeout)) {
                // not need continue.
                break
            }
            p.idles.Remove(e)
            p.release()
            p.mu.Unlock()
            ic.c.Close()
            p.mu.Lock()
        }
        p.mu.Unlock()
    }
}
```

Comment: Select is a blocking statement. It is like a traffic signal where channels are roads. It will wait until at least one of the channels are available for communication. A `default` case would make the execution 'slip' through this default case if no other cases are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
select {
case p.cleanerCh <- struct{}{}:
default:
}
```

This is a non-blocking `select` statement. (because there is a `default:` case)

If there is a receiver goroutine at the other end of the `p.cleanerCh` channel, i.e. there is a goroutine that's currently "waiting" at a receive operation i.e. `<-p.cleanerCh`, then the `case p.cleanerCh <- struct{}{}` is executed immediately which effectively unblocks the receive operation `<-p.cleanerCh` and then the goroutine can proceed to execute whatever statements follow.

If there is no receiver goroutine then the `default:` case is immediately executed and the surrounding `startCleanerLocked` function can proceed to execute whatever statement follow the `select` statement.

---

```golang
select {
case <-ticker.C:
case <-p.cleanerCh: // maxLifetime was changed or db was closed.
}
```

This is a blocking `select` statement. (because there is no `default:` case)

This `select` statement blocks the `for` loop until one of the two communication cases is ready to receive.

Comment: It explains the matter. Thank you for your help,  I have understood what this code snippet do.

Comment: And I confused for `case <-ticker.C` and `case <-p.cleanerCh` ,  the ticker excute `for` body every 100 millisecond,  so why also need `case <- p.cleanerCh` ??  the `case <- p.cleanerCh` seems to no use ? only keep `case <- ticker.C` also work normal?

Comment: `case <- ticker.C` causes the for loop's body to be executed periodically at the specified interval, i.e. every 0.1 seconds. `case <-p.cleanerCh` causes the for loop's body to be executed whenever "needed", i.e. whenever another goroutine explicitly sends to `p.cleanerCh`.

Comment: Oh, I know, Thank you for your answer. Thx

Comment: @AchillesHeel 0.1 seconds may seem like a short period to a human but in a computer quite a lot can happen during that time. The program may be in a state where it needs a cleanup but cannot afford to, or doesn't want to, wait until the current 0.1s period is over. And it is in such a case that the cleaner channel can be used to request a cleanup immediately.